# i ussualy get a problem in "pyrcc5" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyrcc

I am trying to convert qrc file to py but a module error comes up like this

[image]

can we use another or alternative code for conversion?

Answer (score 5):

One possible option is to use the python command that uses pyrcc5:

```py
python -m PyQt5.pyrcc_main resource.qrc -o resource_rc.py
```